# Does Model Driven Architecture play nice with LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

My newly created system was created using the Model Driven Architecture approach so all I have is the model (let's say comprehensive 'Order' and 'Product' classes).  These are fully tested classes that support the business of my application.  Now it's time to persist these classes as objects on the harddrive and at some later time retrieve them in the same state (thinking very abstractly here).  Typically I'd create an IOrderRepository interface and eventually a ADO.NET-driven OrderRepository class with methods such as GetAll(), GetById(), Save(), etc...  or at some point a BinaryFormatter-driven OrderRepostiroy class that serves a similar purpose through this same common interface.

Is this approach just not conducive to LINQ-To-Sql or the Entity Framework.  Something that attempts to build my model from a pre-existing DB structure just seems wrong.  Could I take advantage of these technologies but retain this 'MDA' approach to software engineering?

... notice I did not mention that this was a Web App.  It may or may not be -- and shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think that you should not make types implementing business methods and types used for O/R mapping the same type. I think this violates the single responsibility principle. The point of your entity types is to bridge the gap between relational space and object space. The point of your business types is to have collections of testable behavior. Instead, I would suggest that you project from your entity types onto your business types when materializing objects from the database. Separating these two allows your business methods and data mappings to evolve independently, which is very important, especially if you cannot always control the schema of the database. I explain this idea more fully [in this presentation](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/11/38394/).